# Простые арифметические действия приводят к неожиданным результатам

Tags: python, арифметика

Простые арифметические действия приводят к неожиданным результатам.

```
a = 0.05 * (1 + 0.33025396842916444 // 0.05)
```

на выходе должно быть 0.35,
однако я получаю 0.35000000000000003.
При этом

```
aa = 1 + 0.33025396842916444 // 0.05
```

исправно показывает аа = 7.
Что это за глюк???